# rails with fcgi error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, lighttpd, fastcgi

LoadError (Expected /web/zhao_backend2/app/controllers/admin_controller.rb to define AdminController):
    /usr/local/ruby-1.8.7-p248/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_missing_constant'
    /usr/local/ruby-1.8.7-p248/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:453:in`const_missing'
    /usr/local/ruby-1.8.7-p248/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:465:in `const_missing'
    /usr/local/ruby-1.8.7-p248/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:257:in`constantize'
    /usr/local/ruby-1.8.7-p248/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:148:in `constantize'
    /usr/local/ruby-1.8.7-p248/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/routing.rb:1426:in`recognize'
    /usr/local/ruby-1.8.7-p248/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:170:in `handle_request'
    /usr/local/ruby-1.8.7-p248/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:115:in`dispatch'
    /usr/local/ruby-1.8.7-p248/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:126:in `dispatch_cgi'
    /usr/local/ruby-1.8.7-p248/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.0.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:9:in`dispatch'
    /usr/local/ruby-1.8.7-p248/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.0.2/lib/fcgi_handler.rb:101:in `process_request'
    /usr/local/ruby-1.8.7-p248/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.0.2/lib/fcgi_handler.rb:149:in`with_signal_handler'
    /usr/local/ruby-1.8.7-p248/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.0.2/lib/fcgi_handler.rb:99:in `process_request'
    /usr/local/ruby-1.8.7-p248/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.0.2/lib/fcgi_handler.rb:77:in`process_each_request'
    /usr/local/ruby-1.8.7-p248/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/fcgi-0.8.8/lib/fcgi.rb:612:in `each_cgi'
    /usr/local/ruby-1.8.7-p248/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/fcgi-0.8.8/lib/fcgi.rb:609:in`each'
    /usr/local/ruby-1.8.7-p248/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/fcgi-0.8.8/lib/fcgi.rb:609:in `each_cgi'
    /usr/local/ruby-1.8.7-p248/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.0.2/lib/fcgi_handler.rb:76:in`process_each_request'
    /usr/local/ruby-1.8.7-p248/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.0.2/lib/fcgi_handler.rb:50:in `process!'
    /usr/local/ruby-1.8.7-p248/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.0.2/lib/fcgi_handler.rb:24:in`process!'
    /public/dispatch.fcgi:24

Rendering /web/zhao_backend2/public/500.html (500 Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class name in your /web/zhao_backend2/app/controllers/admin_controller.rb should be

```
AdminController
```

it is case sensitive!